# What is the Chinese-language equivalent of gobase (main resource for SGF files)?

Tags: go

I would find it hard to believe if someone tried to tell me that there was not such a website, and that people in China relied on gobase. Isn't there a Chinese-language resource for SGF files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### TOM qipu

http://weiqi.sports.tom.com/php/listqipu.html

Recent games, download SGF or view online with a java applet.

### Flygo

http://www.flygo.net/jdqp.html

This one is a little gold mine if you know how to parse the page, old Chinese games, recent games...etc (downloadable SGF)

### WeiqiOK

http://www.weiqiok.com/asp/English.asp

They have an english version. The kifu search is at the bottom of the page. (they also have tsumego, fuseki, joseki...etc.)

[Here](http://www.weiqiok.com/asp/ShowPlayers.asp) you can find a list of the players in their database.

### Sina

http://duiyi.sina.com.cn/gibo/new_gibo.asp

On this page you can find recent professional games and games played on sina's weiqi server.

### Eweiqi

http://www.eweiqi.com/qipu_more.asp

The Chinese portal for Tygem also has some Tygem + pro tournament kifu. (need to install an addon for IE to view)

Comment: just out of curiosity, do you know why sina chooses to call it "gibo" instead of "qipu" in the url above? is that the Cantonese pronounciation maybe?

Comment: in case someone else is reading this the subject of foreign-language sites for SGF records, i found this site useful... http://www.kihuu.net/ there were enough records of 久保松勝喜代 to make me happy, at least.

Comment: @magnetar: Gibo is Korean. The web developer is probably Korean or plays on wbaduk too often.